# How to use t3lib_iconworks in the frontend of Typo3?

Tags: php, typo3, sprite

I have a modul in the Backend with some icons included with t3lib_iconWorks. How can I use the same code in a Frontend Plugin?

It seems that the variables like $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['spriteIconApi']['iconsAvailable'] do not exist in the Frontend. Do I have to call something like the following?

```
$spriteManager = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_SpriteManager', TRUE);
$spriteManager->loadCacheFile();
```

If Yes? Where do I have to call it? If I call it in ext_localconf.php $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['spriteIconApi']['iconsAvailable'] it seems to be overwritten later.

I'm using Typo3 4.55

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TBE_STYLES (TYPO3 Backend Styles) don't exist in the frontend. Everything you need to know about using Sprite Icons in your extension can be found here:

http://blog.tolleiv.de/2010/07/typo3-4-4-sprites-in-your-extension/

You can add new sprite icons in ext_localconf.php or ext_tables.php and then use them in your extension.